# SharePoint 2016 - min role advice

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, farm-setup, minrole

We are installing SP2016 for the first time and need some advice about min roles. Its going to be a 2 server farm, I want them to be exactly the same. When going though the setup phase, which min role would I pick?

I presume that in my scenario, you would choose custom?

Might be a silly question but, I need to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with the Custom Role as your requirement is both server should be the same then only Custom Role can give you full ability. Custom role is same as what we have in SharePoint 2013( one role).

Comment: Can distribute roles between two servers? 2 two roles in one server and rest of the roles in another server?

Comment: No, you have only one role but Custom is role which include everything in it. Rest i.e Application or DC or Search or Webfront end roles are subset of the Custom.

Comment: So what's the difference with **Single-server farm**? I am really confused with these two roles? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Custom
Custom service applications, services, and components that do not integrate with MinRole belong on Custom servers. The farm administrator has full control over which service instances can run on servers assigned to the Custom role. MinRole does not control which service instances are provisioned on this role.

Comment: Single-server farm
Service applications, services, and components required for a single machine farm belong on a Single-Server Farm. A Single-Server Farm is meant for development, testing, and very limited production use. A SharePoint farm with the Single-Server Farm role cannot have more than one SharePoint server in the farm.

Comment: Also, I need all of the servers to be exactly the same, ie All of the same components and services so that I can have redundancy and be able to implement  Zero downtime patching.

Comment: yes in custom role you can do it, enable the same services on both server

Comment: That's the msdn documentation? I saw that earlier! Still not very clear. I will dig into it more while installing in my Lab. Anyway thank you!

Comment: big catch is Single-Server is for only one server farm you cannot add more server in the farm while custom role is scaleable.

Comment: That's a very important info!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who arrives here, MinRole is the best practice going forward.  If you are hosting a farm for production/staging purposes, definitely use MinRole.  Microsoft has recently reduced the VM burden by combining some MinRoles like WFE+Distributed Cache, and Search+App.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt667910%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

For a two server farm, use WFE+Distributed Cache, and Search+App.  Search+APP actually includes the WFE role, so effectively you can even use it as a WFE if you want.

MinRole configurations are the only tested scenarios from Microsoft before they release patches.  Being compliant with MinRole gives you power when working with stack overflow/technet forums, or Microsoft support when trying to get help.  Finally, having a hard set of service applications on your farm reduces support burden.  If you really need a custom server, add a server on top of an already compliant MinRole farm.